# How to track clicks of all the users on buttons on Jira website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to pop-up an alert containing the button name whenever the user presses it, not only buttons but also  Tags, now the problem is that there's different types of nesting the button content for example it could be like this:

```html
<button>
  <div>
   //content doesn't matter here
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Button Name </span> I want to display this span inner text
   </div>
</button>
```

or the button tag could have only one child..etc. Here are the code of three clickable elements:

- in the first element I want to display "Create Projects" in an alert window:
  [image]
- and some buttons have their names as a value of an attribute called aria-label like this:
  [image]
- in the first element I want to display "Projects" in an alert window
  [image]

I wrote the following code, and the problem is sometimes when I press the button the alert shows with the button name, and sometimes it doesn't, here's my code:

```
// Queue implementation

class Queue
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.items=[];
    }

    // front function 
    front() 
    { 
        // returns the Front element of  
        // the queue without removing it. 
        if(this.isEmpty()) 
            return "No elements in Queue"; 
        return this.items[0]; 
    } 


    enqueue(element)
    {
        this.items.push(element);
    }

    dequeue()
    {
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            return " Underflow";
        return this.items.shift();
    }

    isEmpty()
    {
        return this.items.length == 0;
    }
}


function BFS(node) {
    let q = new Queue();
    //let explored = new Set();
    q.enqueue(node);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        let currentChild = q.front();   
        q.dequeue()
        let ChildBoy = currentChild.children;
        for (let i = 0 ; i <ChildBoy.length ; i++) {
            q.enqueue(ChildBoy[i]);
            console.log(ChildBoy[i]);
            //explored.add(ChildBoy[i]);
        }


        if (currentChild.textContent != null && currentChild.textContent != undefined && currentChild.textContent != "") 
        {
            alert("textContent"+ "  "+currentChild.textContent);
            break;
        }
        if (currentChild.getAttribute("aria-label") != "" && currentChild.getAttribute("aria-label") != null && currentChild.getAttribute("aria-label") != undefined) 
        {
            alert("aria-label-Content"+"   "+currentChild.getAttribute("aria-label")); 
        }
    }
}

let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (let index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
    let button_i = buttons[index];
    button_i.addEventListener('click', function () {
       BFS(button_i) ;
    });

}



let hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let index_1 = 0; index_1 < hrefs.length; index_1++) {
    let hrefs_j = hrefs[index_1];
    hrefs_j.addEventListener('click' , function()
    {
        BFS(hrefs_j);
    });

}
```

and the manifest json file is:

```
{
    "name" : "first extension",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "extension for track user",
    "permissions" : [
        "storage",
        "declarativeContent",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "page_action" : {
        "default_popup" : "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png",
            "32": "images/get_started32.png",
            "48": "images/get_started48.png",
            "128": "images/get_started128.png"
          }

    },
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : 
        ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : true
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      },

      "content_scripts" :
      [
          {
            "matches" :["https://*.atlassian.net/*/*" , "https://*.atlassian.com/*" , "https://*.atlassian.net/*"],
            "js" : ["track.js"]
          }
      ],

    "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

What's the wrong with this code?

Comment: 1) This is probably a dynamically updated site that changes its pages without reloading them fully from server so your content scripts run just once and attaches the listeners only to the elements that existed at that time. It's better to use just **one** click listener on `document` and simply check event's `target`. 2) This problem should be easy or even trivial to debug if you know how to use devtools, see tutorials. You can set a breakpoint in the code, run it line-by-line and see what happens and the state of DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm please submit your comment as an answer to flag it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution does not seem straight forward to me, since you do not know a class or a unique identifier for all visual buttons...

Therefore I will propose one way of doing it.

First add a global click event lister on the `document` this way you can track all the click and just select what you want.

Something like this, a simple way to see what are you clicking. (maybe you can find a solution just around this)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const elementType = event.target.tagName;

  console.log(elementType + ' clicked!');
});
```

```html
<div>Test1</div>
<span>Test2</span><br>
<button>Test3</button><br>
<a>Test4</a><br>
<button>Test5</button><br>
<div>
  <button>Test6</button>
</div>
<p>Test7</p>
```

Then you will have somehow to whitelist what is a button (as you cannot take only the  tags)

So for this I was thinking about creating an array or a map (if possible) of [XPaths](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xpath_intro.asp) and verify if the clicked element matches with your whitelist. Only then you will get the text.

Note: XPath is a unique path of a node in DOM. That also means you will have to know all XPaths of your buttons.
Usually XPath are not lightweight on terms of performance, but if you run only on click and you find an optimized solution, it should be ok...

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
// Using object for performance reasons.
const ACCEPTED_XPATHS = {
  '/html/body/button[1]': 1,
  '/html/body/button[2]': 1,
  '/html/body/div[2]/button': 1,
  '/html/body/div[3]/div/span': 1
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  const elementXPath = xpath(element);
  
  // You can use this to collect your accepted list:
  console.log('CLICKED PATH = ' + elementXPath);
  
  if (ACCEPTED_XPATHS[elementXPath]) {
    console.log('BUTTON CLICKED --- Button Text: ' + element.innerHTML);
  }
});

// https://gist.github.com/iimos/e9e96f036a3c174d0bf4
function xpath(el) {
  if (typeof el == "string") return document.evaluate(el, document, null, 0, null)
  if (!el || el.nodeType != 1) return ''
  if (el.id) return "//*[@id='" + el.id + "']"
  var sames = [].filter.call(el.parentNode.children, function (x) { return x.tagName == el.tagName })
  return xpath(el.parentNode) + '/' + el.tagName.toLowerCase() + (sames.length > 1 ? '['+([].indexOf.call(sames, el)+1)+']' : '')
}
```

```html
<div>Test1</div>
<span>Test2</span><br>
<button>Test3</button><br>
<a>Test4</a><br>
<button>Test5</button><br>
<div>
  <button>Test6</button>
</div>
<p>Test7</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <span>THIS IS ALSO A BUTTON</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have a better idea right now, Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanx bro <3 <3

Comment: @YamenJbara could you please upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful? Thanks